# I am trying to combine a constant with a set of other HTML but I am getting an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, concatenation

I have a a const which is below:

```
 const subMenu = this.props.content.Children.map(item => (
      <li
        className="mobile-menu-overlay__submenu-items text-capitalize"
        key={item.Title}
      >
        <a href={item.Url}>
          <strong>{ item.Title }</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
    ));
```

And want to combine it with the following HTML after it is done looping:

```
' <li className="mobile-menu-overlay__submenu-items text-capitalize feature-link">
        <strong><a href={this.props.content.Link.Src}>{this.props.content.Link.Title}</a></strong>
    </li>'
```

I want the result to be the following but I keep getting errors:

```
 const subMenu = this.props.content.Children.map(item => (
      <li
        className="mobile-menu-overlay__submenu-items text-capitalize"
        key={item.Title}
      >
        <a href={item.Url}>
          <strong>{ item.Title }</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
    )) + ' <li className="mobile-menu-overlay__submenu-items text-capitalize feature-link">
        <strong><a href={this.props.content.Link.Src}>{this.props.content.Link.Title}</a></strong>
    </li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **map()** call returns an array of JSX but you are trying to concatenate with a string.

Try using the array **concat()** method to add on the additional element.

Something like this:

```
const subMenu = this.props.content.Children
  .map(item => (
    <li
      className="mobile-menu-overlay__submenu-items text-capitalize"
      key={item.Title}
    >
      <a href={item.Url}>
        <strong>{ item.Title }</strong>
      </a>
    </li>
  ))
  .concat([
    <li
      className="mobile-menu-overlay__submenu-items text-capitalize feature-link"
      key={this.props.content.Link.Title}
    >
      <a href={this.props.content.Link.Src}>
        <strong>{this.props.content.Link.Title}</strong>
      </a>
    </li>
  ])
```